# raise KeyError in python

Tags: python

While running a python script (not mine), I get this error

```
  File "/home/mahmood/parboil/driver/process.py", line 74, in makefile
    for makeargs in os.environ['MAKE_ARGS'].split(" "):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'MAKE_ARGS'
```

I don't understand what is the problem exactly? Is `MAKE_ARGS` something unknown for 2.7? This file is called from upper level files and I am trying to understand it for further debugging. Any idea?

Comment: `os.environ['MAKE_ARGS']` - that's supposed to be coming from the environment, nothing to do with Python version.

Comment: `os.environ['MAKE_ARGS']` it is mean you should export env variable something like `export MAKE_ARGS=blabla`

Comment: Need to set the environment variable `MAKE_ARGS` before accessing it using `os.environ[]`.

Comment: It is a bit safer to use it like this: `os.envron.get("MAKE_ARGS", "")`. You could even provide default values like this:  `os.envron.get("MAKE_ARGS", "--arg1 --arg2")`.